# how to programatically simulate a oracle server shutdown

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am looking for ideas to programmatically create oracle server shutdown condition for testing purposes. It is difficult to a) get access to the database for security reasons, and b) the server needs to be up 24x7 and can't afford to shut down at will. Installing another server is very time consuming as the application I am debugging connects to a DB that has thousands of tables that require 'valid' data in many of them,  and compiled stored procedures- ie bringing up the app without all the schemas, some ref data, and stored procedures is virtually impossible. Our product is developed in c++ and uses OCI for the DB interface. Is it possible to tweak DB layer code in the debugger and create a condition such that OCI APIs are forced to return 'shutdown' err code without coring the application?

Comment: Is creating a development instance and restoring the entire database from backup an option? In my experience that's how development databases are created.

Comment: I don't know that there's a way to get the OCI client to do that. As a general rule, this sort of failure testing shouldn't be done in production anyway. You seriously need a separate test environment.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to have a dedicated Oracle user for testing purposes, and just lock the account.